# Ideal Hostnames Number to Parallelize Downloads

Tags: performance, browser, hosting, loading, cdn

We are setting up a CDN to serve CSS, JS and the images. We are wondering what will be the ideal number of hostnames to distribute the ressources across. This technique is use by many websites to increase parallelize downloads and page loading. However, DNS lookups slow down the page loading so the rule is not the more hostname you have, the more performance you will get.

I've read somewhere that the ideal number is between 2 and 4. I wonder if there is a rule of thumbs that apply to all webpages or if there is a rule of thumbs according to the number of ressources being served and the size of them.

Specific case : Our websites are composed of two kinds of pages. One kind serve a list of thumbnails (15-20 or so images, varying) and the other serve a flash or shockwave application (mostly games) with a lot less images. Obviously, we have regular JS, images and CSS on all pages. When I mean regular, that correctly optimized elements, 1 CSS, a few images of the UI, 2/3 JS...

I will love to have answers for our specific case but I will be also very interested to have general answers too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (Yahoo!) did a [study](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/) back in 2007 that showed that 2 is a good number, and anything more than that doesn't improve page performance, in some cases having more than 2 domains degraded performance.

What I would recommend is - if you have a A/B testing infrastructure then go ahead and try it out on your site, use different number of domains and measure the page load time from your end users. 
If you don't have a A/B testing framework then just try a different value for few days, measure it, try a new one, measure that ... do this till you find that point where performance starts to degrade.

There is no silver bullet for this recommendation. This is something that depends a lot on how many assets are there on each page and what browser (number of parallel downloads) your end users use. Hope that helps.